# geom_histogram conditional color aes

Tags: r, ggplot2

Why is the following happening?

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_histogram(aes(gear, color = gear > 3), binwidth = 1, fill = NA)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**edit**
As you can see, the colors do not respect the given condition: the first color (here "ggplot pink") also outlines the top border in the range of the second break, where I would only expect "ggplot bluegreen" in this example.

I would like to conditionally change the color for the bars. I have the feeling that this might be because ggplot might not know how to map the aesthetic to the correct x values. But how to do that ? I surprisingly found no question on SO to that yet, but will keep looking.

I know I could simply split the data frame and draw `geom_histogram` for each split, but is there an option using a conditional statement within `aes()`

Comment: Can you elaborate what's the issue with the result you are getting?

Comment: @Z.Lin Thanks for your request. I have added this to the question.

Comment: I think it's because `geom_histogram`'s default position is stack. The pink lines appear on top of gear = 4 / 5 because they are 0-count bars with 0 height, stacked above the blue bars with a positive height. If you mapped `gear > 3` to a fill aesthetic, this wouldn't be an issue because a bar / rect with 0 height would not have a visible fill. But since it's mapped to a colour aesthetic, a 0 height bar / rect shows up a completely flat horizontal line. Try adding `position = "identity"` & see if that's closer to what you have in mind?

Comment: @Z.Lin It comes close! but now the green color marks the bottom. Yes, the stacking is very likely the reason for this behavior. I guess the workaround of one histogram for each data range is what I need.

Comment: You may also want to consider cutting the bins yourself & plotting with `geom_bar` instead of `geom_histogram`.